# Factorization Manipulation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Consider $t=x^2+10y^2-6xy-4y+13$. So what is the $t$ as smallest number? The solution is $9$.

My trying:

$$t=x^2+10y^2-6xy-4y+13$$

$$=x^2+9+10y^2-6xy-4y+4$$
   $$=(x+3)^2-3x+2y(5y-2)-6xy+4$$.

So let $x=-3$ and $y=0$. From this I got $t=13$. My answer is false. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Gauß' method to write a quadratic form as a linear combination of squares of linear forms:
\begin{align}
t&=x^2+10y^2-6xy-4y+13 =(x-3y)^2 -9y^2+10y^2-4y+13 \\
&=(x-3y)^2+y^2-4y+13 =(x-3y)^2+(y-2)^2-4+13\\
&=(x-3y)^2+(y-2)^2+9.
\end{align}

Comment: thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get everything into squares or constants, since otherwise you can't minimise all the individual terms. The fact that you have an $xy$ term and a $y$ term, but no $x$ term, suggests you want something of the form
$$(ax+by)^2+(cy+d)^2+e.$$
Can you find values of $a,b,c,d,e$ to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
$$t=x^2+10y^2-6xy-4y+13=x^2-6y \cdot x+10y^2-4y+13,$$which could be regarded as a quadratic function with respect to the variable $x$.

Hence, $$t \geq \dfrac{4\cdot 1 \cdot (10y^2-4y+13)-(-6y)^2}{4 \cdot 1}=y^2-4y+13=(y-2)^2+9\geq 9,$$ with the equality holding if and only if $x=-\dfrac{-6y}{2 \cdot 1}$ and $y=2$,namely, $x=6,y=2$.